# pyqgis - edit attribute table; records NULL instead "0.0"

Tags: python, gis, qgis, pyqgis

I am writing a function to register values ​​in the attribute table to record:

```
    def process(self):
        """Fill dimension field with TOPSIS -rank- value """
        provider = self.activeLayer.dataProvider()
        if provider.fieldNameIndex(self.parameters['dimension'])==-1:
            self.activeLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(self.parameters['dimension'], QVariant.Double,"",24,4,"")] )
            #edit is a shortcut that replaces layer.beginEditCommand and layer.endEditCommand
        with edit(self.activeLayer):
            for f,i in zip(self.activeLayer.getFeatures(),range(len(self.relativeCloseness))):
                #print(self.parameters['dimension'],self.relativeCloseness[i])
                f[self.parameters['dimension']] = self.relativeCloseness[i]
                self.activeLayer.updateFeature(f)
```

If self.relative Closeness [i] has a value ! = 0, the values ​​will records correctly, but if the values ​​are == 0, in the attribute table the values ​​will recorded with "NULL" value. Could anybody help me to understand where is the problem?
[attribute table example with null values instead zero values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtABi.png)